# How to handle mutations when using vuexfire with modules?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules, vuexfire

The following is written in regard of using mutations together with modules in the [vuexfire documentation](https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire/tree/master/packages/vuexfire), together with some code snippets:

Add the mutations to your root Store and make sure to define the property you want to bind in the state first:

```js
import { vuexfireMutations } from 'vuexfire'
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    todos: [], // Will be bound as an array
    user: null, // Will be bound as an object
  },
  mutations: {
    // your mutations
    ...vuexfireMutations,
  },
})
```

It works with modules as well, **but you should not add the mutations there**:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    todos: {
      state: {
        todos: [], // Will be bound as an array
        user: null, // Will be bound as an object
      },
    },
  },
})
```

The question is what is the correct way to handle mutations in a bigger project? If I have a project with about 20-30 modules, do i put all the modules mutations into the root object? Do I create an extra file for my mutations or what is the correct way to structure this?